# How to run any Transformation Logic on HDFS data which is at Remote PC

Tags: python, apache-spark, hdfs, remote-access

I have huge size data (in TBs or PBs) in my HDFS which is located at remote PC. Now instead of taking Data to the Transformation Logic (which is not correct and efficient), I want to run my python Transformation Logic itself on the location where my Data is stored.

Seeking some useful ideas about the technologies which can be used to fulfill this requirement.

Things which I tried till now:

1) Approach 1

- Took SSH Connection of Remote PC (where HDFS data is available), Copied my python Transformation Logic there and executed after fetching the data from HDFS.

2) Approach 2

- Loaded HDFS data to Apache Spark RDDs which is on Remote PC where HDFS data is available and executed Spark Job from another PC.

Please suggest other technologies which can be used for Logic Execution remotely.

Comment: *after fetching the data from HDFS* -- Not clear how you did this for TB / PB worth of data (assuming you don't have a single machine with that much storage itself)... The "correct" solution is using YARN and submitting Spark code there... Yes, it'll take worth to write Hadoop InputFormats for "non-standard" data-formats, but that isn't specfic to Spark or Python in any way

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting up a Spark Cluster in the same local network where you have the data and running spark transformations in the cluster remotely (SSH or Remote Desktop). The advantages of the setup are:

- Network Latency will be minimised as the data is transferred in the
  same network locally.
- Running the transformations with distributed and in-memory processing engines like Apache Spark is fast.

**Note: Please ignore if the response is in line with your second approach**

Comment: I have already tried this approach. But problems which I faced are; Spark doesn't support many data formats and it is very tough to develop interface between spark jobs and other libraries (for ex: cv2).